# Select first child of a div that has a container

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following html:

```
<form action="">
  <div class="cont">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cont">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cont">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I would like to select only the first form group.

This is easily achievable when `.form-group` is not contained by `.cont`, working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/eqrbw9zx/3/).

I've been trying with what's below and similar things:

```
form .cont .form-group:first-child{
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

I understand why this doesn't work, easily visualized [here](https://jsfiddle.net/eqrbw9zx/4/).

[Here's a live explample.](https://jsfiddle.net/eqrbw9zx/6/), how can I select only the first form group?

Comment: what this?  form .cont:first-child div.form-group { ...

Comment: @daremachine exactly that, in retrospect it's very simple, I was just blocked somehow in only putting first-child in the last part of the selector.

Comment: example is here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_firstchild_more2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your HTML in the second example, you could select the first `.form-group` element in the first `.cont` element:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/p74sg375/)

```
form .cont:first-child .form-group:first-child {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

If there aren't multiple `.form-group` elements nested in the `.cont` element, like in your third example, you could omit the `:first-child` pseudo class from the `.form-group` element:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/azc36duh/)

```
form .cont:first-child .form-group {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

---

Of course, this won't work in *all* instances, such as when the first `.cont` element doesn't contain a `.form-group` element. It's worth pointing out that your selector `form .cont .form-group:first-child` wasn't working because the `.form-group` elements aren't sibling children elements.

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I needed, so simple yet it never crossed my mind!! Thanks a lot, I will accept the answer asap!